# Move items up in a list

Tags: list, f#

How do you move items up in a list.
The input list would look like: `let list = [1;2;3;4;5]`
And the output list would look like one of the following:
`[1;2;3;5;4]`
`.........>`

`[2;1;3;4;5]`
`...>......`

Plot twist: I want to be able to move any index in the list up

From what I understand is this not something you aim to do with F# or functional languages, but it's a must have on my program.
I believe this can be done using both recursions and higher order(HO) functions, but since my knowlegde with HO's are very limited I tried to solve this using a recursion.

My approach to moving down an item in the list included a simple recursion with index and list as arguments like so:

```
let rec moveDownAt index list =
    match index, list with
    | -1, _ -> list
    | 0, h1::h2::t -> h2::h1::t
    | index, h::t -> h::moveDownAt (index - 1) t
    | _, [] -> list
```

However, to move in the other direction I would need to reference the previous "head" and I assume I would have issues on the third match line `| index, h::t -> h::moveDownAt (index - 1) t` where i perform h:: since I add the head to the list (which would be the previous the next call if I add that argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching place on two elements means that one is moving up, and one is moving down.
Simple using the following code will solve the problem:

```
let moveUpAt index list = moveDownAt (index-1) list
```

This will displace the index making "index to be moved down" turn into "index to be moved up".

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is the following: First, return the `n`th element of the list. Then append the rest elements, except the `n`th element since you have already returned it. Here's the code:

```
let MoveToTop index xs =
    List.nth xs index           // take nth item
    ::                          // and prepend it to the beginning of the
                                // original list, except the nth element
    (
        xs                      // original data
        |> List.mapi
            (fun i x -> i, x)   // associate each element with its ordinal index
        |> List.filter
            (fun (i, _) -> i <> index) // allow only the elements whose index
                                       // is not equal to requested index
        |> List.map snd         // remove the index from the data
                                // as we no longer need it
    )

// test
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
|> MoveToTop 1 // don't forget, the index is zero-based
|> printfn "%A"
// output: [2; 1; 3; 4; 5]
```

Note that if `index` is outside the length of the list, an `ArgumentException` will be thrown.

A recursive algorithm is also possible, but it would be certainly less performant due to creation of excessive data and performing excessive computations.